# cpr library missing from alpha release of Atmosphere

Tags: java, eclipse, frameworks, backend, atmosphere

I am not able to get any of the samples working for the latest version of 3.0.0alpha-2 working for Atmosphere framework. I would like to implement a servlet, but in the previous versions this was org.cpr.AtmosphereServlet (2.4.9) now the directory does not exist. Is there any way I can implement a servlet in the alpha build?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just looked at the changelog.
Renamed org.atmosphere.cpr => org.atmosphere.runtime

Looks like all the samples are made with stable versions under alpha.